# Consulta Entity Framework de un objeto que tiene una lista como propiedad

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, entity-framework

Tengo un objeto que lo filtro de esta manera

```
data= data.Where(e => !e.EsBaja).ToList();
```

A su vez tengo una propiedad tipo lista adentro de data llamada childs.
La lista childs tiene propiedades, una es Disabled. 
Por ejemplo si un item de esa lista esta en Disabled, no deberia mostrarlo.

Quisiera traer toda la data pero solo con los childs que no esten en disabled.

Intente algo asi pero no estoy haciendo lo correcto.

```
data = data.Where(p => p.childs.Any(c => c.Disabled != true));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = data//.Where() el Where afecta la colección donde se llama
.Select(p => {// por cada elemento de la lista
      // actualizar su propiedad childs por la lista filtrada donde 
      // c.Disabled != true
      if(p.childs != null)
         p.childs = p.childs.Where(c => c.Disabled != true).ToList();
      // retornar el elemento p con su propiedad childs actualizada
      return p;
 });
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ahora tengo otro problema, en algunos items de data no tengo listado childs, por ende cuando quiere aplicar la condicion y no la tiene me da error. Como podria validar que solo cuando childs != null valide q sus items sean Disabled != true ?

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias! Justo lo que necesitaba! Anduvo barbaro! :)